# Service worker not receiving old push notifications click event in windows 10 for chrome

Tags: service, notifications, push, onclicklistener, worker

when we have 2 are more push notifications in windows 10 notification history then only latest notification is opening in browser when click on it for chrome. But in firefox and edge browser all notifications are opening in browser.

Here is my service worker code.
Push event:

```
if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
        return;
    }
    var data = {};
    if (event.data) {
        data = event.data.json();
    } else {
        console.log('received empty data for push notification');
    }
    let notificationTitle = data.title;
const notificationOptions = {
        body: data.bodyText,
        icon: data.imageUrl,
        sticky:false,
        notificationCloseEvent:false,
        data: {
          url: data.conversationUrl,
        },
      };
     const message = {notificationTitle, notificationOptions};
      const promise = isClientFocused()
                        .then((clientIsFocused) => {
                            if (clientIsFocused) {
                                console.log('App is in focus no need to show notification');
                                return;
                            } else {
                                return firstWindowClient().then((windowClient) => {
                                    console.log('URL is already in open');
                                    windowClient.postMessage(message);
                                }, () => {
                                    console.log('Url is not in open.');
                                    return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
                                });
                            }
                        });
      event.waitUntil(promise);
    });
```

Notification click event:

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', (event) => {
       const urlToOpen = new URL(event.notification.data.url, self.location.origin).href;

  const promiseChain = clients.matchAll({
    type: 'window',
    includeUncontrolled: true
  })
  .then((windowClients) => {
    let matchingClient = null;

    for (let i = 0; i < windowClients.length; i++) {
      const windowClient = windowClients[i];
      if (windowClient.url === urlToOpen) {
        matchingClient = windowClient;
        break;
      }
    }

    if (matchingClient) {
      return matchingClient.focus();
    } else {
      return clients.openWindow(urlToOpen);
    }
  });

  event.waitUntil(promiseChain);
    });
```

Comment: [John Doe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8407395/john-doe) [asks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58754937/3744182) *Were you able to resolve the issue ?*

Comment: No. I didn't find solution for it